# MD5 Cross-platform decryption from VBA to C#

Tags: c#, vba, encryption, md5

I'm creating a new application in `C#` for my company.

Our SQL database stores passwords for users using a **MD5 encryption** which is created through another application we have using `MS Access` in `VBA`.

We used code from this website - http://www.di-mgt.com.au/crypto.html#MD5 for our **VBA application**.

I read on that site that it should be possible for me to decrypt the passwords on another platform: http://www.di-mgt.com.au/cryptoCrossPlatform.html

But I'm not sure how I can do this in `C#`.

I also looked into some code from `CodeProject` - But the decryption is pulling back a different result to what is already stored in our database. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38951/How-To-Hash-Data-Using-MD-and-SHA

How can I validate logins from this in my new `C#` application?

**EDIT:**
This is the Hash I'm using at the moment.

```
   /// <summary>
    /// take any string and encrypt it using MD5 then
    /// return the encrypted data 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="data">input text you will enterd to encrypt it</param>
    /// <returns>return the encrypted text as hexadecimal string</returns>
    private string GetMD5HashData(string data)
    {
        //create new instance of md5
        MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();

        //convert the input text to array of bytes
        byte[] hashData = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(data));

        //create new instance of StringBuilder to save hashed data
        StringBuilder returnValue = new StringBuilder();

        //loop for each byte and add it to StringBuilder
        for (int i = 0; i < hashData.Length; i++)
        {
            returnValue.Append(hashData[i].ToString());
        }

        // return hexadecimal string
        return returnValue.ToString();

    }
    /// <summary>
    /// encrypt input text using MD5 and compare it with
    /// the stored encrypted text
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="inputData">input text you will enterd to encrypt it</param>
    /// <param name="storedHashData">the encrypted text
    ///         stored on file or database ... etc</param>
    /// <returns>true or false depending on input validation</returns>
    private bool ValidateMD5HashData(string inputData, string storedHashData)
    {
        //hash input text and save it string variable
        string getHashInputData = GetMD5HashData(inputData);

        if (string.Compare(getHashInputData, storedHashData) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: MD5 is a 1-way hash, there is no decryption.

Comment: You hash the password the user typed in and compare it with the one that's already in the database. Not the other way around.

Comment: @Rinecamo You should just post that as answer.

Comment: @Nyerguds As you wish.

Comment: I think that's what I've managed to do so far but the `MD5Hash` i'm using is bring back a different hash to what is stored so i'm wordering are there different types of hashs?

Comment: This then sounds a bit like the Hash function of the VBA part not being correct. Are you sure that the Hash function in the Access/VBA project is generating proper MD5 hash? AFAIK there is no built in hash function in VBA, so probably something went wrong in that implementation.

Comment: Hash with both functions (VBA and C#) and compare it with the hash you get from http://www.md5.cz/ . Then you know which function is not working correctly.

Comment: results of the checksum - In SQL the password is stored as `25D55AD283AA400AF464C76D713C07AD` when i do a checksum of the hash method in C# i get - `2bc5b8a7c7097da7917e6c1c0d52a59c` so they aren't matching

Comment: Well yeah, but what does http://www.md5.cz/ say?

Comment: Also it might be worth checking if the Access/VBA code is using some sort of salt when generating the hash code.

Comment: ah right md5.cz says that the one stored in SQL i.e. the Access/VBA code is correct meaning the one in `C#` is incorrect. But i'm not sure what is incorrect with it

Comment: The `.ToString()` is missing something. Try `hashData[i].ToString("X2")` inside the for loop.

Comment: @Rinecamo Wow that worked! Can you explain what the X2 does? it now returns the same code!

Comment: @cocojay The X2 tells the method to output the string in hexadecimal.

Answer (score 5):

You hash the password the user typed in and compare it with the one that's already in the database. Not the other way around.

Answer (score 5):

> Our SQL database stores passwords for users using a **MD5 encryption** which is created through another application we have using `MS Access` in `VBA`.

No you don't. [MD5 isn't **encryption**, it's a hash function](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/08/you-wouldnt-base64-a-password-cryptography-decoded). It's also not well-suited for passwords. You may want to hit the brakes and read up on [how to safely store passwords in C#](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/02/how-safely-store-password-in-2016#csharp).

#### Instead of MD5, use [Martin Steel's fork of Bcrypt.NET](https://github.com/martinsteel/Bcrypt.NET)

```
// Calculating a hash
string hash = BCrypt.HashPassword(usersPassword, BCrypt.GenerateSalt());

// Validating a hash
if (BCrypt.Verify(usersPassword, hash)) {
    // Login successful
}
```

Simple, easy to reason about, and secure.

Answer (score 1):

You **MD5** approach to passwords is not secure, as the method is subject to [rainbow table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) attacks.

To illustrate the problem, try searching your encoded password that you mention in the comments [25D55AD283AA400AF464C76D713C07AD](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=25D55AD283AA400AF464C76D713C07AD) in your favorite web browser, and you will soon see that it's listed as 12345678

You need to step up your security and introduce some [secure password hashing](http://security.blogoverflow.com/2013/09/about-secure-password-hashing/)

Comment: Yes I appreciate that it's old tech and not secure by today's standards but it's purely for internal company software which doesn't reach the outside world fortunately. If we build any products that face outwards then we will definitely step up the security. But thanks for the concern!